# Azure Data factory Unauthorized Issues While Connect Azure DataBricks Notebook Trigger PipeLine

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

We are trying to execute notebook in ADF pipeline and it is throwing the error because of we are trying to connect azure key vault to fetch the credentials to authenticate our API's but if we run in ADB level, we are not get any issues. only happening while trigger in ADF pipeline level. also we enabled all the required permission like get and list but not able to resolve the issues, please help us.

> com.databricks.common.client.UnexpectedHttpError: HTTP request failed
> with status: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you may have enabled `Enable admin protection for “No isolation shared” clusters on your account` feature across the workspace. If yes, then that could be the reason why jobs are failing as it was hitting limitation with this admin protection. For more info about the limitation please refer to this document: [Enable the account-level admin protection setting - Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/no-isolation-shared#limitations)

[image]

Then, to overcome this issue, Azure Databricks recommends that admins do one of the following:

- Use a different cluster type other than “No isolation shared” cluster access type or its equivalent legacy cluster types.
- Create a non-admin user when using No Isolation Shared clusters.

Comment: Thanks for the update!
Above option is not working.
We are trying to run the job using new job cluster every time.
No isolation - disabled

Comment: isolation --disabled

Comment: Dear All, please help us the issues still persist, we fixed in development environment for this issues after upgraded the cluster version but not able to resolve in QA environment. kindly advice what is needs to enable for permission